# Java PostgreSQL arrayList<Object[]> insert code- applying to any number of colums

Tags: java, postgresql, arraylist

I've got a method in Java for inserting an ArrayList into PostgreSQL.

```
public void postgreSQLInsert(String tblname, String col1, String col2, String col3) throws SQLException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<Object[]> insertList = voltdbresultarray;

    if (insertList == null) {
    } else {
        for (Object[] columnValues : insertList) {
            try {
                System.out.println(columnValues[0]);
                System.out.println(columnValues[1]);
                System.out.println(columnValues[2]);
                String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tblname + "(" + col1 + "," + col2 + "," + col3 + ") " + "VALUES (" + columnValues[0] + ", '" + columnValues[1] + "', " + columnValues[2] + " );";
                postgresStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            } catch (PSQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate!");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Col1, col2, and col3 are all column name strings created elsewhere, and voltdbresultarray is a static array given values earlier. It all works fine, but only for object arrays with three columns. I'd like to make it applicable to object arrays with any number of columns, but I can't figure out how. Is there a way to have it take any number of column arguments and create the correct SQL query from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could use [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) and change the method signature from

```
public void postgreSQLInsert(String tblname, String col1, String col2, String col3)
```

to

```
public void postgreSQLInsert(String tblname, String... columns)
```

and then something like

```
if (insertList == null) {
} else {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.append("INSERT INTO ").append(tblname);
  sb.append(" (");

  for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
      sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(columns[i]);
  }
  for (Object[] columnValues : insertList) {
   StringBuilder valueSB = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < columnValues.length; i++) {
      if (i != 0) {
        valueSB.append(", ");
      }
      System.out.println(columnValues[i]);
      valueSB.append("'").append(columnValues[i]).append("'");
    }

    try {
      String sql = sb.toString()
          + "VALUES (" +  valueSB.toString() + ")";
      postgresStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (PSQLException e) {
      System.out.println("Duplicate!");
      continue;
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for, yeah. What's valueSB supposed to do? It's coming up red.

Comment: @user3779281 Edited to add missing declaration.

Comment: Ah. Well, it looks like it's working. Is there a way to have it print out the correct values, like it did before?